# Determining the group generated by a set of roots?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

I have a set of 45 roots and I want to know which group is generated by the corresponding generators.

In the set are 5 diagonal (=Cartan) generators

$$ (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)_1,(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)_2,(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)_3,(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)_4,(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)_5$$

Therefore the generated group has rank $5$.

16 of the weights are of the form

$$ (1/2,1/2,-1/2,-1/2,-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2) \quad, \quad  (-1/2,-1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,\sqrt{3}/2) \quad , \quad \ldots $$

and 24 are of the form

$$ (0,1,0,1,0,0)  \quad, \quad  (1,0,0,1,0,0)  \quad, \quad  (0,0,0,2,0,0)  \quad, \quad (1,0,-1,0,0,0) \quad, \quad  \ldots $$
***How can I determine which group is generated by these roots?***

Rank 5 with 45 generators would fit perfectly with $SO(10)$ and indeed some of the roots do coincide with $SO(10)$ roots. Unfortunately, the 16 weights that do look so different are not part of the $SO(10)$ set of roots. Is it $SO(10)$ nevertheless, because of some change of basis?

Comment: Do you know already whether the group is simple? If so, $SO(10, \Bbb C)$ is the only possibility (in the complex setting).

Comment: @Travis the group can be semi-simple, too.  Nevertheless, if it must be $SO(10)$ how can I see it from the roots alone? The roots I wrote in the OP are a subset of $E_6$ roots (in a physical context after Higgs symmetry breaking). Are there allowed transformations that enable me to transform these roots into the obvious $SO(10)$ roots?

Comment: Checking the dimensions of all simple Lie algebras of rank $< 5$ shows that there are no semisimple possibilities: No algebra of rank $< 4$ has dimension more at least $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 45$, so one proper summand  would have to have rank $4$, but all of these have dimension $\leq 36$, and the only rank $1$ simple algebra has rank $3$. Anyway, it certainly *looks* like $SO(10)$ (I think these are the correct number of short and long roots for one). One way to prove this would be to find a basis of positive roots and align these first with the roots of $SO(10)$ in your preferred realization.

Comment: (As you probably know, $\mathfrak{so}(10)$ is the subalgebra determined by all of the simple roots of $\mathfrak{e}_6$ excluding the first, so if you generated the subalgebra this way, you're essentially done.)

Comment: @Travis thanks a lot for your comments! I now do understand that it must be SO(10) but I'm still not sure why the roots look so different from the usual SO(10) roots. Surely there must be some change of basis or sth similar that maps the roots I quote in the OP to the usual SO(10) roots

Comment: Yes, there must be, by the classification of simple root systems. Barring some deeper insight into what's going on with this particular normalization, probably the method I suggested above is the easiest possible for aligning these, i.e., for finding an appropriate transformation of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ taking these roots to your preferred roots.

Comment: @Travis Yes thanks, I'm trying to this just now. By "align these first with the roots of $SO(10)$" you mean I search for some matrix that transforms my simple roots into the simple roots of $SO(10)$?! Why is such a transformation "allowed"? I suspect this is possible because there is some freedom in choosing the Cartan generators, i.e. their diagonal entries (see my new question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352609/freedom-in-choosing-the-cartan-subalgebra/1352880#1352880), but I would love to hear your thoughts about it

Comment: @Travis I was now able to find a map, that maps my simple roots to the simple roots of $SO(10)$ unfortunately applying the same map to all other roots does not yield the correct set of $SO(10)$ roots

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest except asking a new question and including enough explicit data that someone can diagnose what's gone awry.