# Freedom in choosing the basis of the Cartan subalgebra?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

*Although the answer by Qiaochu Yuan helps me, a concrete example would answer my question completely. I recently [read](https://books.google.de/books?id=Az73BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=%22inner%20automorphism%22%20root%20%22outer%20automorphism%22&source=bl&ots=Z6XdSegp5K&sig=Th2iSnyeOgLgyzjcxsczc8e1vQg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CGoQ6AEwCGoVChMIurSJlr_pxgIVBIpyCh3PkAwP#v=onepage&q=%22inner%20automorphism%22%20root%20%22outer%20automorphism%22&f=false) that "roughly spearking [automorphism are] permuation among roots". What is some concrete example for an inner automorphism and how does it change the corresponding Cartan subalgebra?*

What transformations are allowed regarding the Cartan subalgebra of a given algebra?

Weights for every representation are labelled by the corresponding eigenvalues of the Cartan generators. Therefore the weights depends on how we "choose" the Cartan subalgebra.

On thing that isn't fixed is the ordering of the Cartan subalgebra elements $H_1, H_2, \ldots$. 
For example,
$$ H_1  \leftrightarrow H_2 \quad \text{which means for the weights} \quad  (w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,...) \leftrightarrow (w_2 ,w_1,w_3,w_4,...) .$$

Is the choice of the Cartan subalgebra elements and therefore the labelling of the weights in some sense fixed (except for changing the order as discussed above) or can we, for example build (orthogonal?) linear combinations of the Cartan subalgebra elements and get again an allowed Cartan subalgebra?

For example

$$ \tilde H_1 \equiv H_1+H_2 \quad \text{and} \quad \tilde H_2 = H_1-H_2, $$

which would mean for the weights

$$(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,...) \rightarrow  (\tilde w_1,\tilde w_2,w_3,w_4,...) $$

Any idea would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Lie algebras that have Cartan subalgebras, not Lie groups. Cartan subalgebras of a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ are [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subalgebra#Existence_and_uniqueness) to be unique up to automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$; for example, choosing a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is more or less equivalent to choosing a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (the Cartan subalgebra consists of matrices which are diagonal when written in that basis).